# Mvvmcross Subscription message firing stalls for 20+ secs after first viewmodel is shown

Tags: mvvmcross

In some of my my viewmodels and some background running services, I need a second tick for all sorts of actions such as Statemachine progression etc..
To avoid having to create a Timer for every occasion, I have one TimerService which publishes a Messenger plugin message every second.
Those viewmodels or Services that need it just subscribe to this message.
This has worked well for over a year. Recently I noticed a rather long startup time of my app. After some debugging I found that after the launch of the first Viewmodel (it is correctly displayed), it takes about 25secs before the subscriptions start picking up on this message. Seems like something is holding back the publishing of these messages.
During those 20+ secs there is no activity by MvvmCross at all. Nothing is logged by Mvvmcross at all.

What could cause such behaviour ? When in the startup sequence does the messenger plugin start distributing its messages ?

I apologise for not posting code here, as it is a phenomenon that is just happening across the whole application. None of the singleton services that run in the background pick up these messages until after 20secs everything starts working properly.

EDIT: MvvmCross V3.5 is used along with latests stable updates of Xamarin. Problem occurs on every Android version tested.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting (and reading all the MvxMessenger docs again) I tried using the SubscribeOnThreadPoolThread method instead of simple subscribe for one of the published messages that typically triggers updating the properties of a viewmodel on a regular basis in its handlers. This made the problem go away.
Normally the handling if this viewrefresh message is fast and doesn't require more then copying repository values (that are updated by a background service) to the visible viewmodel properties. I guess there's somewhere a synchronous call in one of the refresh handlers that make the messenger system block.Haven't found it yet.
What are typical situations that can make the Messenger plugin block ? I would be very interested to understand that a little better.